# How to find a number before a string using preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-replace

I use the following code to find a number **after** a word in a array. which is working fine

```
   $searchkey = array('rs','balance is now','total');
    $data = "20960.00 of vTopUp transferred to your account, Your balance is now 21450.00 of vTopUp . No.is KONTH/1402/C00392.";
        foreach($searchkey as $key){
            $result=preg_match_all("/(?<=(".$key."))\s*([0-9,]+[.\d][\d]*)/i",$data,$networkID);
            if($result){$myanswer = @$networkID[0][0];break;}
        }
echo $myanswer;
```

Note : the $searchkey is fixed and the $data is not fixed.

Now I would like to find a number **before** a wrod in an array

```
$searchkey = array('of vTopUp','is success');
```

for the above data the result should be

```
20960
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse your regular expression like this:

```
/([0-9,]+[.\d][\d]*)\s*(?:(?!".$key.").)*/i
```

`(?!".$key.").)*` will match everything up to, but not including your key.